# call method AFTER textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like to call my login method AFTER the keyboard was dismissed - since I want to start animation and change the UIView alpha to 0.5 until the response.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.passwordText){
        //hide the keyboard
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

        [self validateCredentialsRemotely];

    }else{
         [self.passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The keyboard is not being dismissed **before** the call to the method `validateCredentialsRemotely` and the screen freezes while the keyboard is displayed. I would like it to be dismissed first, and then call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this notifications..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

In keyboardWillHide method call your validateCredentialsRemotely method,This may solve your first issue

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == self.passwordText){
    //hide the keyboard
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    [self performSelector:@selector(doAnim) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    }else{
        [self.passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)doAnim {
    //start animation
    self.view.alpha =0.5;
    [activityWheel startAnimating];
    //validate user
    [self validateCredentialsRemotely];
    //end animation
    [activityWheel stopAnimating];
    self.view.alpha =1;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. but it doesn't work. The keyboard is being displayed while validateCredentials is being displayed

Comment: @Odelya please make sure if textfieldshouldReturn is being called or not! You can check it by either debugging or inserting NSLog statement at the method start!

Comment: also make sure if control comes inside "if (theTextField == self.passwordText)" condition and resignfirstresponder method gets called